# Que regiones han sostenido el crecimiento en Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

Tengo un Dataframe, que es un excel que exporte donde me salen distintos tipos de regiones con sus respectivos PIB en trimestres. Me preguntan que segun estas cifras cuales han sostenido el crecimiento, como lo puedo formular

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.